# Kendo UI Angular - kendo-numerictextbox - display a year as a number without thousand separator

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to use a `kendo-numerictextbox` to input a year however I cannot find the format that doesn't display a thousand separator. With a US culture, "2017" appears as "2,017".

```
<kendo-numerictextbox 
        [(value)]="myModel.year"
        [autoCorrect]="autoCorrect"
        [format]="'n0'"
        [min]="2017"
        [step]=1>
    </kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to adjust the format input of the NumericTextBoxComponent, like this:

```
<kendo-numerictextbox 
        [(value)]="myModel.year"
        [autoCorrect]="autoCorrect"
        [format]="'#'"
        [min]="2017"
        [step]=1>
</kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Example Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EeGPbvlxBLFQ406Qs2VP?p=preview